# Why is meniscus formed?

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension

Why does water tends to form meniscus (as it increases the surface area) if it has the tendency to lower the amount of free surface?

Comment: [See](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=2220)

Answer (score 3):

A meniscus is formed because the adhesive and cohesive forces don't balance each other perfectly,so there can be extra pull/push due to the force between the surface of the container and the fluid, which forms a meniscus

Answer (score -1):

Adhesion is responsible for a meniscus and this has to do in part with fluid's fairly high surface tension. Fluid molecules are attracted to the molecules in the wall of the glass beaker and since fluid molecules like to stick together, when the molecules touching the fluid cling to it, other molecules of fluid cling to the molecules touching the glass, which forms a meniscus.
If you want more clarification about this topic, then consult online tutors of TutorEye.